# MySQL: Can stored procedure information be extracted from the information schema?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, schema

Is it possible to retrieve stored procedure information like `name`, `parameter nane/position/type` from the Information Schema in MySQL or possible in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a lot of information, including the name, from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`.  [See the MySQL Manual for details.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/routines-table.html)

The parameter information would be contained in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` table, but this table is not available in MySQL, so I'm not sure that you can get that information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

If you just need the argument list, you can select the procedure names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` then get the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements for each of them using [`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html).  If you just need the arguments and types, you should be able to parse them without too much trouble.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS does not seem to exist..?

Comment: Nope.  It _was_ in MySQL 6, but it was never backported to MySQL 5.

Comment: grrrr so no way on generating stored procedure classes from the database?

Comment: You can use `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html) and parse it yourself... if you're just parsing the parameter list, that wouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like what you are looking for is possible using MySQL's built in backup program: mysqldump. Give this a try:

```
mysqldump --routines --triggers --nodata --skip-opt YOURDB
```

Details: A quick look at the [documentation (MySQL 5.4)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/mysqldump.html) shows you definitely want to run it with the `--routines` option, as well as probably `--triggers`. I'm guessing you'll want to skip most of the data in this dump, just to look at the procedures, in which case you may want the options `--nodata --skip-opt` and probably some other options I haven't identified yet. Check out the documentation for your version for whatever other options you want. Also note you can specify just some of the tables in the DB by adding their names on the end.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, i think James' solutions is sufficient, but I will surely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, PARAMETER_MODE, PARAMETER_NAME, DTD_IDENTIFIER
FROM information_schema.parameters
WHERE specific_name = routine_name;
```

This will list the routine IN/OUT parameters.