# Fetching Stored Procedure from the MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

Is there any tool to find out stored-procedure and its parameters list from the database? I am just implementing in to the swing application where user will give the database name only and on the basis of db name i have to fetch all the stored procedure and its parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `SELECT name,param_list FROM mysql.proc WHERE db='your_database' and type='procedure';` to retrieve the list of all procedures and their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS
```

will show you the available stored procedures.

For fetching procedures for a particular database, use -

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS 
WHERE Db = 'your_database_name';
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582221/245679) answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks sayem for quick reply...but how can we fetch the parameters of particular stored procedure??

Comment: thanks again sayem..is there any java api which will help me to find the stored procedure and its parameter??

Comment: @user591790: I am afraid I am not aware of any such API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/). It will show you everything that is related to your database including your stored procedures.

Comment: thanks paulius for quick reply...but this is individual tool. I can not use this in my swing application.. is there any java API which will help me to find out the stored procedure and its parameter for every database not only for MySql database.

Comment: This is pure java based tool and will find parameters for every database not only MySql.

Comment: ok paulius..does this provide any Java API that i can use in my swing application?

Comment: No it does not. It is commercial, not open source.